# Does the union of all these neighborhood cover $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

Consider the rationals in $[0,1]$. Around each I take a neighborhood (possibly of different radii). Is the union of all these neighborhood sure to cover $[0,1]$? What if I had used irrationals instead of rationals?

Comment: Hint: Let $q$ be a point in the interval. There's a sequence of rational (irrational) numbers converging to $q.$

Comment: so, what r u going to conclude? @ Whsan M. Kermani

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani: Chera hint ro post nakardi? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Take your least favourite irrational $\alpha$ in the interval $[0,1]$. For every rational $r$, you can construct an interval $I_r$ with centre $r$ that avoids $\alpha$.

Comment: since $\alpha$ is dense, so it must contain a rational..right? @ André Nicolas

Comment: $\alpha$ is a real number, not an interval. There's no question of it being dense or containing a rational.

Comment: @Mathematics: The question was whether the union of the neighbourhoods **must** cover $[0,1]$. The above answer produces an example where $[0,1]$ is **not** covered, since the particular real $\alpha$ is not in the union of the intervals. One can do much better, by having the union cover an arbitrarily small proportion of $[0,1]$. However, that takes more work, and the construction above is enough to answer the question.